# Вывод данных из 3-х таблиц в одну (mysql, php)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно вывести данные из трех таблиц в одну?
Ниже прикладываю скрины таблиц:

1 таблица - tb_clients:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2 таблица - tb_orders:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3 таблица - tb_items

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо получить таблицу следующего вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробовал разные запросы, толком ничего не получилось. Возможно таблицы не верно составлены, но пытался сделать по следующей логике - завожу клиента, к клиенту цепляю заказ, к заказу цепляю позиции.
Программка работает корректно, но вот вывести так сказать сводную табличку со всеми заказами в таком виде не получается.
Если не трудно подскажите советом куда копать.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `tb_items.client_id` избыточный столбец.  что вы пробовали сделать то? два джойна вам тут нужны. приведите ваши запросы, найдем в них ошибку.

Comment: Вообще никаких проблем вывести через join'ы с выборкой нужных полей. Просто разберитесь с синтаксисом.

Comment: Вот такой запрос выводит почти все что нужно:
`$sql = "SELECT tb_orders.id, tb_clients.client_company, tb_orders.order_data, tb_orders.order_manager, tb_orders.order_status 
            FROM tb_orders 
            INNER JOIN tb_clients ON tb_orders.client_id=tb_clients.id";`

Но мне нужно еще присоединить сюда третью таблицу tb_items, чтобы вывести столбец с информацией о позициях заказа.

Comment: Сможете помочь дописать запрос? Начал прикручивать еще один INNER JOIN и стало фигню выводить))